# Getting deployment error with Delphi 11.3 and an FMX app for OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, codesign

I must have changed something in my build because it used to be OK. Situation is a Delphi FMX application set to build for OSX. The debug build works fine and once upon a time I was able to Deploy and get a zip file of the app on the Mac Mini like I should. But now I get:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E0264 Unable to execute '"/usr/bin/codesign" -o runtime --timestamp --deep -s "Developer ID Application: David Baxter (DYVQN6TA94)" -f "/Users/davidbaxter/PAServer/scratch-dir/Dave-Mac Build/CuePlayerPro.app"' (Error 1)
> [PAClient Error] Error: E0264 /Users/davidbaxter/PAServer/scratch-dir/Dave-Mac Build/CuePlayerPro.app: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

How do you recover from this? What could I have changed to cause this? Again, it's Delphi 11.3.1 running on Windows 11 sending to a Mac Mini running 13.4 and the current Xcode. Thank you.

Comment: It's possible you added something to the deployment that is either creating an invalid folder structure, or including a file in an invalid location in the bundle. Check the deployment in Deployment Manager in Delphi

Answer (score 0):

It was, indeed, something I added. So that others don't fall into the same situation - the problem appears to come from my doing a deployment before adding my .icns file to the deployment list. Delphi added one of its own "CuePlayerPro_PROJECTICNS.icns" as a default. Later, I added the real .icns file to the list. I noticed that there were two icns files, but Delphi did not allow me to delete the one it added, so I figured it must need to be there. Among many things trying to fix the deployment, I clicked the "Revert to Default" button, which **did** delete the PROJECTICNS file and allow the deployment to proceed.